# Using pill capsules to give cat Atopica?

Tags: cats, medicines, scratching

I've read about people using empty pill capsules to give cats Atopica. Our cat needs to take .35ml of it. Just wondering what size pill capsules people are using?

Answer (score 4):

There are [purpose-built pill capsules for cats](https://capsuline.com/collections/capsules-for-cats), even the smallest size should easily fit a 0.35 ml dose. Although you have the choice between different flavours, an additional [pill gun](https://www.mikkipet.com/?mikki_care=pill-gun) might also come in handy.